# Why does the R have two libraries by default?

Tags: r, windows

This is the first one: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.1\library

There is another one: C:\Users\Asus\Documents\R\win-library\3.4

I installed R all by default. Some packages are in the first library and some are in the second one.

Comment: Could you tell us which packages are in either library after a default installation? My guess would be that all base packages should be in the system library (`…\Program Files\…`), whereas user installed packages will go into the second library.

Comment: Look at the result of `.libPaths()` -- on my system it is three directories.  Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: > .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/Asus/Documents/R/win-library/3.4"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library"

Comment: When i was using R 3.31(i guess?) there was only 1 library. Now im usin 3.41

Answer (score 11):

By default, R use a system library where base packages are installed and a user library where packages are installed.

It is all defined in `.libPaths()` which is used by default by `lib` arg in `install.packages` (see help file) The first element of `.libPaths()` is used as default path for installing package. All paths are used to look for a package when you load them with `library()` with first path priority.

On my system, which is windows too, I have the same as you :

- system library in the folder where R is installed
- a user library in the `Documents` folder of my user.

you can see [libPath help page here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/libPaths) (or type `?.libPaths()` in console) for how to tweek the default behaviour with environment variable.

Comment: Can i change the default path?

Comment: Yes you can change it. It is explained in the help page I linked to. `.libPaths(<new_path>)` will change the default library for example. If you put that in you `.Rprofile`, it will change at startup. You could use environment variable too. see the help page